# _end symbol disappears when linking to libcurl

Tags: linux, linker, gnu

On Linux, the D runtime library relies on the `_end` symbol in determining the GC root ranges (`man 3 end`), which is in fact very similar to what the Boehm GC does. However, when linking in libcurl, the symbol is no longer found by the linker:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char _end[];
int main() {
    printf("%p\n", &_end);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc test.c # works
$ gcc test.c -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccOPtbEv.o: undefined reference to symbol '_end'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_end' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From a quick search on the D forums, libpq, libdw and several other libraries seem to trigger the same problem. Any idea what could be happening here? **`test.c` doesn't even depend on symbols from libcurl.** (Arch Linux x86_64, GCC 4.7.2, ld 2.23)

Also, please note that »try linking in libssl« is not the answer I am looking for, I want to understand what is happening here. I'm trying to fix this problem in a compiler I'm working on, so you can assume basic familiarity with how the linking process works.

Edit: The reason why I'm not particularly satisfied with telling the users to just link in libssl, ..., explicitly is that `pkg-config --libs curl`, `curl-config --libs`, etc. don't contain this information; requiring it would thus break build systems. If anyone has a better idea for determining the bounds of the data (initialized and BSS) segments, I'd be keen to know.

Edit 2: With the toolchain mentioned above, `end` (without the underscore) also seems to be defined, and it doesn't trigger the problem. Still baffled as to why it occurs, though.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -g -o test test.c` compiles without warnings or errors using `gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5`, with or without `-lcurl`.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for the data point. It occurs on several different Arch Linux installations and at least one other distro (http://forum.dlang.org/thread/j2424m$23e4$1@digitalmars.com – Arch doesn't have `lib64`)…

Answer (score 0):

> please note that »try linking in libssl« is not the answer I am looking for.

But most likely it actually *is* the answer you are looking for. Your command line is *all wrong*. Try this instead:

```
gcc test.c -lcurl
```

The order of libraries and sources,objects on command line matters.

Comment: I actually suggest `gcc -Wall -g test.c -lcurl -o mytestprogram`; get the habit of using `-Wall` (and also `-g` for debugging purposes) and always name the produced binary (`a.out` is an historical artefact). Avoid naming a program `test` (which is a shell builtin, like `cd` is). And `-rdynamic` could also be useful when you want to access at runtime the program's symbol.

Comment: Please re-read my question - I was asking if anybody had an idea what is happening here _because test doesn't even depend on symbols from libcurl_, so it shouldn't matter at all. The problem in reality occurs with a compiler I am working on, and the order is obviously correct there. For this reduced test case, it doesn't matter. I reversed the order anyway as to not mislead people into answering hastily.

Answer (score 0):

_end symbol is provided by linker. It points past the last object in bss. However, it's just a convention, no standard requires this. Your toolchain's linker doesn't do that, apparently.

Comment: You missed the point that the symbol exists if libcurl is not linked in.