# Free Pascal compiler failed to link with error "heaptrc.o: undefined reference to symbol '_end'"

Tags: libcurl, freepascal

I am trying to compile a program with Free Pascal, with  `-gh` flag to turn on heaptrc to find out memory leak and get error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/fpc/3.0.4/units/x86_64-linux/rtl/heaptrc.o: undefined reference to symbol '_end'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

If I turn off `-gh` flag, my program successfully built.

Previously `-gh` flag was working fine. It seems it happens after I run [Free Pascal cross compiling](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling#From_Linux_x64_to_Linux_i386) or after install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`. I don't know and can't remember.

Why is error message triggered?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/end.3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here, Jonas Maebe's answer from [FreePascal forum](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,45730.0.html)

> It seems that linking libcurl somehow hides the "_end" symbol: [_end symbol disappears when linking to libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328144/end-symbol-disappears-when-linking-to-libcurl)
>
> -gh needs this symbol to know where the initialised data section ends. I'm not sure there's anything FPC can do to fix this, since it apparently also happens with gcc (and I'm not aware of another easy way to detect that address).